# ArcGIS Pro rotate point symbol smaller than one degree

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

Is it possible to rotate a point symbol by an angle smaller than one degree?

When i try to enter 0,5° in the Angle field of the Symbol pane it gets rounded to 1°. 0°30′ doesn't work either.

My workaround solution would be to rotate the underlying .svg file, but that's not a nice solution.

Maybe it is feasible in Python?

Comment: Same when I try it. But it is possible to use a field in the attribute table to hold the angles then use the field values as rotation. I tried using 0,5 and 1, no errors but I cant tell if there is a difference in symbol rotation in the map.

Comment: @BERA It works and is a better solution than my workaround, although it still is a bit of a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that even though the value shown after you type in 0.5 is 1, the angle is set to 0.5. This can be checked using arcpy:

```
import arcpy
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps('Map')[0] #Change to match your map name
lyr = m.listLayers("bs_riks")[0] #Change to match your layer name
sym = lyr.symbology
print(sym.renderer.symbol.angle)
```

[image]

(To set symbol angle:

```
sym.renderer.symbol.angle = 0.5
lyr.symbology = sym
```

)